# Optimising python code by not referring the variable which refers to other variable and so on

Tags: python, optimization, memory-management

I have a question of optimization when I refer to a variable which then refers to a variable and so on, does every time I mention the last variable which holds the previous variable all code is being executed again?

For example my code:

```
a = 5
b = 6
c = b * 2
d = a + c
e = c + d
f = e + d + c
g = f
h = g
```

And now in my code, I say `print(h)`, does everything has to be calculated again or python holds all values in memory when I reference them? I've came across this when I am working with SQL and pandas in python, when I connect to a database, take what I need, transform the data, then load it to a dataframe, create 3 new dataframes out of the original one and mention one of those 3 dataframes which has `1,000,000` rows and `50` columns, does python keep all those million records in memory?

Thank you for your suggestions, I assume there is a nice article somewhere explaining this but I haven't exactly find what I am looking for.

Comment: `g = f`, for example, is *not* a "variable referring to another variable".  Variables refer to *values*, in this case a value that came from another variable, but there's no ongoing connection with that other variable, nor with any of the calculations that led up to that variable's value.  The value in this case is simply an integer.

Comment: Okay, so for example if I have `a = 1`, `b = a + 1`, `c = b + b`. When I call `print(c)`, does, not sure how to name it, compiler/python/memory management system has memory slots allocated for `a`, `b` and `c` and that's it, or when I call `c` the calculatons are re-done. As I understand the code runs from top to bottom and once it''s compiled it is put to a single line that does not look back when running it?

Comment: The `c` in your example is indistinguishable from `c = 4` - the calculations are one-time events, no history is kept.  No changes to `a` or `b` will have any effect on `c`.

Comment: It will have an effect on `c` if I change `a` or `b` value and call `c` again the second time, right? And to the real-world example, when I create a dataframe with `1,000,000` rows and make lets say 10 new dataframes where I simply multiply the values of the original dataframe by a different number, now there are 11 different dataframes of `1,000,000` rows in memory or there is a different way that python stores these dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are supposed to propose a trimed out version of your problem to build a minimal example. Here your code is close to minimal but unfortunately unrelated to the described problem.

What matter when it comes to memory are objects and not variables. In Python a variable is no more that a name that referes to an underlying object. Simply an object ends its lifetime and can be garbage collected to free memory as soon as it is no longer reachable, meaning as soon as no variable can access it directly or indirectly.

Examples:

```
a = "foo and bar"  # ok a addresses the string
b = a              # b addresses the same string (one single copy)
a += "s"           # oops...
```

A string is a non mutable type. The last line then creates a new string (addressed with `a`), while `b` still addresses the old one. After `b = None`, the old string will no longer be reachable and will be garbage collected.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]   # ok a point to the list
b = a              # b addresses the same list
a.append(5)        # oops...
```

A list is a mutable type. `a.append(5)` changes the object and both `a` and `b` now address the list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Just use `print(a,b)` to see that...

---

Now for your exact question:

pandas underlying containers are numpy array which resides in memory. If at a moment, you can access 3 distinct dataframes, then they will be present in memory. But... pandas is highly optimized. That means that if you use sub dataframes, and depending on gory details, you will get either a plain copy (duplication in memory) that you will be able to change independently of the original dataframe, or a view (same memory used).

Let us look at some pandas examples:

Say `df` is a 1,000,000 rows dataframe with only numeric data. All those rows are loaded in memory.

After:

```
for i in range(2, 11):
    dg = df * i
    ...          # process dg
```

For each step you build a new copy of the dataframe but it will be destroyed on next step. Long story short, you will use twice the initial dataframe memory

```
dfs = [df * i for i in range(2, 11)]
for dg in dfs:
    ...         # process dg
```

Here you build 9 new dataframes that will be accessible through dfs so you end with 10 distinct dataframes and need 10 times the initial memory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so if I have 3 variables that mention each other and does not do anything with them, for example `connection='connection_to_sql_and_retrieving_million_rows'` and `second_connection = connection` python will not connect and retrieve a million rows twice because both variables point to the same memory location. In other words, I can reference variables as many times as I want and memory will not be affected as long as nothing changes in the object I am referring the variables to.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis: yes that is what I meant.